# Add a back arrow to leftBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I want to add a back arrow to a `leftBarButtonItem`, to make it appear visually as if it was a regular back button, although it's functionality is slightly different.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use `Custom UIButton` for that with back image .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824186/trying-to-handle-back-navigation-button-action-in-ios/18824282#18824282

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use custom button and hide the back button if you are using navigation controller.

To hide back button use this:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

And for Custom Button:

```
UIButton * customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[customButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:197.0/255.0 green:190.0/255.0 blue:157.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[customButton setTitle:@"Do Something" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
customButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:11.0f];
[customButton.layer setCornerRadius:3.0f];
[customButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[customButton.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[customButton.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
customButton.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 50.0, 25.0);
[customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(customMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem * customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];
customItem.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customItem;
```

This will work for you.
**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using UINavigationController and then push new viewcontroller it will automatically show back button.
If you are Not Using **UINavigationController** than

Use Custom UIButton for that with back image

```
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 48, 37);
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
backButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;

UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back-button.png"];
[backButton setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

backButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);

UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
```

You can change the value for the frame and the imageEdgeInsets as per your requirements.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16603533/1597744) SO Answer.