# How use Back Button in Navigation Item

Tags: ios, swift

When  a have an `ViewController` and insert  `Navigation Item`  create automatically a Back  button.  In my tableView  i use an `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to case into the `ViewS` and this views are using the same navigation Item, but dont create the back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do a push in your previous view controller in the method tableView:didSelectedRowAtIndexPath:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  var newViewController = ..
  self.navigationController!.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
 }
```

And it is done. The back button is already there.

Answer (score 1):

The back buttons are created automatically on a push/segue. If you want to create this functionality yourself you would have to set the `leftBarButtonItem` property of the UINavigationItem and implement a method to call:

```
func backBTPressed() {
     self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(yes)
}
```

See:

[Add a back arrow to leftBarButtonItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971119/add-a-back-arrow-to-leftbarbuttonitem)

[creating back arrow shaped leftBarButtonItem on UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310454/creating-back-arrow-shaped-leftbarbuttonitem-on-uinavigationcontroller?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try unwind segue. Check the following link.

[Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81880/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-2)