# Disable user interaction with different ui elements immediately after tapping on a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, touch-event

I need to disable all user interactions with other ui elements immediately after the user taps on a button. I want to prevent the user from triggering multiple actions at once, for example pressing a button and tap on an element in a collection view or a tap on a UIBackBarButton.

So as an example I created a UIBarButtonItem that calls this method, that disables user interactions of self.view and the UIBarButtonItems and re-enables them again after 1 second:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;

// ... show an alert view

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
    });

}
```

The problem is, that if I tap this button and for example the back button almost simultaneously, it shows the alert view and pops the current viewController.
I assume, that it waits a few milliseconds to determine, if this event is a single touch or multiple touch event (e.g. double tap), but I couldn't figure out how to handle this.

What can I do to disable the user interactions immediately after the user tapped this button?

Comment: I believe your action is on `UIControlEventTouchUpInside `. Make it to `UIControlEventTouchDown `

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I made a little mistake in the description of example. I actually created a UIBarButtonItem to call this method. And this is not an inheritance of UIControl, so there is no way to change the UIControlEvents. I updated the question.

Comment: my answer will still remain same. create [uibarbutton as uibutton as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16603533/1066828). now for uibutton, make event to UIControlEventTouchDown. You are done :)

Comment: I think the problem is that `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` doesn't has an action or target with it, it is just for appearance, you should create a  `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` and disable it when you touch the button.

Answer (score 2):

The appearance of the `UIAlertView` should prevent further user interaction. You're saying, though, that there is a very short window ("a few milliseconds" is a *tiny* delay as far as the user perceives it) in which the user could touch up on some other button, and cause weird behavior. Ok, without testing, I'll just take that as true.

One rather brute-force way to do this would be to set `exclusiveTouch` to `YES` on the button in question. See the [Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW15) for a full explanation. Basically, when a view whose `exclusiveTouch` property is `YES` is tracking a touch, no other views may track touches. Similarly, such a view may not begin tracking touches unless no other views are tracking touches.

A sidenote: I think you're using `dispatch_after` to get a block onto the main queue. Typically you'd just use `dispatch_async` if your intention is to put something on the main queue for immediate execution.

**EDIT:** When this question was asked, it did not specify the use of `UIBarButtonItem`. This answer will only work with `UIView` or a descendant thereof.

Comment: You're right, my apologies. But even so your answer helped me a lot. Thanks for that.