# navigationController popViewControllerAnimated is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in ios development and I want to add back button in my app.
For this I write code in `-(view)didLoad`:

```
UIButton *btnbarBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnbarBack.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 22);
[btnbarBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_left.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnbarBack addTarget:self action:@selector(OnClick_btnBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *btnbarBack_1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnbarBack];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnbarBack_1;
```

and I use popViewController to go back
Clickevent code is :

```
-(IBAction)OnClick_btnBack:(id)sender  {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But when I click on button event fires but no change appear!

I already tried:

```
-[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.navigationController.parentViewController animated:YES];

-[self.parentViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

-[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

But these 3 also not working. Is there any other option to solve this problem.

Comment: Saying something "doesn't work" provides no information what so ever. Explain what _is_ happening when you press the button. Is the button not showing? Is it going to the wrong controller? Is it happening but it's not animated?

Comment: I edited my question,plz refer that..I want to just clarify that event fires,that I already checked but code is not working

Comment: Please check the viewController's hierarchy.

Comment: Yea, viewController hierarchy is correct..I just checked

Comment: If the method is getting called NSLog the navigation controller: NSLog("%@", self.navigationController);

Comment: Can you check the self.navigationController.viewcontrollers?

Comment: First of all, `self.naviagtionController.rightBarButtonItem` is `UIBarButtonItem` type. However, you are assigning a `UIButton` to it. This is not proper already. Take a look at this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451639/custom-uibarbuttonitems-from-uibuttons-with-custom-images-is-it-possible-to-ma

Comment: @YuchenZhong: I think there is not any problem with UIBarbuttonItem & UIButton, because button shows at front side & click event fires but doesn't go to previous screen..Here I clarify that I tried UIBarButtonItem as back button but still It doesn't work..Please give me another solution..Thank you in advance

Comment: Which method to use to navigate to the previous screen is really depending on how the view is created. So, could you shows us code about how you enter the current view? If you are using storyboard instead of code, could you simply take a screenshot of that or explain what segue you are using? Also, could you add a NSLog() in your `OnClick_btnBack` just to make sure the method is being called when you tap on the button.

Comment: @YuchenZhong:yea..I had put alert ,and checked, but clickevent fires,It is worked perfect ,there is not any storyboard or xib file,only .h & .m files are there..actually It is existing app,and I have to do some changes in it..plz help..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're recreating a button that is already in your storyboard. If it isn't, you have an `IBAction` connected to something in the storyboard. Change the "`IBAction`" in the parentheses to "`void`" and that should fix it.

Also...why not create `Uibarbutton` with a custom method and set the image in there?

Comment: ya..I have changed IBAction to void but not found any changes..back button doesn't work..and also tried UIbarbutton but doesn't effect anything..click event fires,but doesn't go previous screen...Is there any other solution???plz help

Comment: Do you have a storyboard?

Comment: No there is not any storyboard or xib ,only .h and .m files are there...I have one existing app and I have to do some changes in it.and put back button right side in navigation controller is one of them....

Comment: @VidhiTrivedi interesting way to build an app. I think storyboards are so easy to use! Especially in a situation like this.

Comment: You are absolutely right ,but In existing app I can't use that,plz give another solution..totally frustrated with this small-big problem..help me..Thx in advance

Comment: How you tried to `po self.navigationController.viewControllers` in the debug **OR** `NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController.viewControllers);`? To see what view controllers are in the navigationController's stack? @VidhiTrivedi

Comment: You also said this was an existing app. Which part did you change? @VidhiTrivedi

Comment: In my existing app, in screen, left side - left navigationcontroller(side menu)  is there -it works perfectly and I want to add Back button at right side(This is change ) and I suffer problem with that as you know..